# PaginatedDataTable change "Rows per page" String

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, datatable

I am using PaginatedDataTable in my app and I got it working perfectly. But I want to change the String of "Rows per page" which is shown in the image bellow. I want to change it to something like "MY Rows" or "Rows in a page" or ... .
[image]

````dart
PaginatedDataTable(
  header: Text(widget.chartsInfo.title),
  rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
  availableRowsPerPage: [5, 10, 15],
  columnSpacing: 15,
  onRowsPerPageChanged: (int value) {
    setState(() {
      _rowsPerPage = value;
    });
   },
   sortColumnIndex: _sortColumnIndex,
   sortAscending: _sortAscending,
   onSelectAll: _resultsDataSource._selectAll,
   columns: dataColumns,
   source: _resultsDataSource),```
````

Comment: Hi, did you know how to add searching filter inside PaginatedDataTable?

Comment: Hi, @uyhaW . I have not implemented that yet. But you can add a textfield and button above the table and search your list when user clicks the button, then setState.

Comment: @ArashMohammadi hello, did u find the solution?

Comment: @TimeToCode I don't fully remember now, but i brought the whole package to my `lib` folder, then changed everything there, I changed a lot of widgets and I thing that `Text` widget was there too. Let me know if you need more help, I'll look at my code.

Answer (score 1):

The text in the footer isn't available to be edited. As a workaround, you can customize your own PaginatedDataTable by copying the Widget on `paginated_data_table.dart`. The footer text "Rows per page" is defined with `rowsPerPageTitle` and can be located on `footerWidgets`.